# Mootools not show colspan td in tr hidden

Tags: css, mootools, html-table

I want to hide information that is in a hidden row as shown no respect colspan. I have:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
    <td><div id="se">click here!!</div></td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="display:none;;">content</td></tr>
```

and Mootools code

```
$('se').addEvent('click',function(){
    this.getParent('tr').getNext('tr').getElement('td').setStyle('display','block');
});
```

when I click on "click here!" hidden row is shown, but not colspan.

See example here: http://jsfiddle.net/Xvnhw/1/

Comment: Welcome to Stackoverflow! When you get a answer that solve your problem please click to mark it as accepted. All the best!

Answer (score 2):

this is not to do with MooTools but browser repaint of an element that it has not considered for rendering before.

move to using a CSS based setup, which gets applied after the engine parses the cells and sets correct position.

http://jsfiddle.net/Xvnhw/3/

```
$('se').addEvent('click',function(){
    this.getParent('tr').getNext('tr').getElement('td').removeClass('hide');    
});
```

and css

```
.hide {
    display: none
}
```

yet another example of why inline element styles are a bad thing.

Comment: The issue is not due to inline styling. It is due to the display style being set to 'block'.

Answer (score 0):

This has nothing to do with inline styling and everything to do with the display value. The display style should be set to 'table-cell', not 'block'.

Here is the original code, with the only change being change being setting the display value to 'table-cell':
http://jsfiddle.net/L2zz3/

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
<tr>
    <td><div id="se">click here!!</div></td>
    <td>value 2</td>
    <td>value 3</td>
</tr>
<tr><td colspan="3" style="display:none;;">content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Mootools code:

```
$('se').addEvent('click',function(){
this.getParent('tr').getNext('tr').getElement('td').setStyle('display','table-cell');

});
```

Note how this example has inline styles and still works.

Here is a CSS based setup that sets the display value to 'block':
http://jsfiddle.net/z7hXc/

HTML:

```
<table width="100%" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="1">
    <tr>
        <td><div id="se">click here!!</div></td>
        <td>value 2</td>
        <td>value 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr><td colspan="3" class="hide">content</td></tr>
</table>
```

Mootools code:

```
$('se').addEvent('click',function(){
    this.getParent('tr').getNext('tr').getElement('td').removeClass('hide').addClass('show');

});
```

CSS:

```
.hide {
    display:none;
}
.show {
    display:block;
}
```

Notice how this example has the same issues as the original code, but does not use any inline styles. Therefore, this is clearly an issue with 'display':'block', and not due to inline styling.

Comment: technically, this is a non-semantic solution that forces your app and CSS to know the default display property of an element. which is why the best practice is to __add__ `display: none` via a CSS class and then take it away, restoring whatever was there previously without having to know the type of element it is, if it's `inline`, `inline-block`, `block`, `list-item`, `table` or `table-cell`. you focus on __hiding__ and restoring via a CSS delta.